# Efficiently Merge values from table2 into table1

Tags: mysql

Look at the following SQLFiddle for reference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f02ca/1

I have two nearly identical tables. I want to determine the difference between the table data, update one table with the different data from the other table.

```
table1
|| *id* || *some_id* || *timestamp* ||
||    1 ||         A ||       01:00 ||
||    2 ||         B ||       02:00 ||
||    3 ||         B ||       01:00 ||
||    4 ||         A ||       02:00 ||
||    5 ||         A ||       03:00 ||

table2
|| *id* || *some_id* ||
||    1 ||         B ||  <-- some_id is different than table1
||    2 ||         B ||
||    3 ||         B ||
||    4 ||         A ||
||    5 ||         B ||  <-- some_id is different than table1
```

So I want to update table1, with new `some_id`'s from table2. I can easily find the differences between the two tables:

```
SELECT t2.id
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.some_id != t1.some_id
```

Result:

```
1, 5 (the id's of the table2 rows that have a different some_id).
```

I thought I could do this type of query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET some_id = 
    (SELECT some_id FROM table2 WHERE id IN 
        (SELECT t2.id 
        FROM table2 t2
        LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id 
        WHERE t2.some_id != t1.some_id ))
```

I thought that query would update `table1` with new `some_id`'s from `table2` but only for rows where the `some_ids` where different between them. But I get the following error:

```
SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause
```

Am I on the right track here? If so, how do I get around this problem? Is there a better or more efficient way up accomplishing this?

A couple notes:

1. It's important that I do not just update or insert everything from `table2` into `table1`, because of the `timestamp` column. That column will update itself when the row is updated. The only rows I want updated in `table1` are the rows who's `some_id` is different in `table2`. So essentially, the `timestamp` column is there to show when that row was last changed.
2. It's important that this is done in as few queries as possible and that they are done efficiently. In my simple example here, there are only 5 rows per table, but in reality my tables have many thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need an UPDATE with a JOIN:

```
UPDATE     table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON         t1.id = t2.id
SET        t1.some_id = t2.some_id
WHERE      t1.some_id != t2.some_id
;
```

The join is basically same as in your SELECT statement except it doesn't need to be an outer join, because, as I understand, you only want to update rows where `id`s match.

Here's a SQL Fiddle demo for this query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58eb8/1.

Comment: Thanks this worked, but it was hella slow for how many rows I had. I will need to figure out something else more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not. In MySQL, it is not possible to  modify the same table from which the SELECT is done.

Check these: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.